# VTK Hello World program i(Cylinder Rendering example)

Tags: image-processing, graphics, vtk

I am trying to run VTK Hello World program i.e. Cylinder Rendering example but I am encountering 2 errors like this one #ifdef __cplusplus extern "C" { #endif  // your function declarations  #ifdef __cplusplus } #endif.... What do I do?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by regenerating the project using cmake. I guess there was some configuration problem earlier.